# Results printing to console but not to the file

Tags: java, csv, file-io

I'm trying to print to a .csv like so:

(A and B are ArrayLists of type String)

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(csvFile);
    System.out.println(A.get(i)+", "+ B.get(i));
    output.println(A.get(i)+", "+ B.get(i));
}
```

I'm getting the desired results to the console, however when I try to overwrite the file I am reading from, it is completely blank.  Any ideas?  I do need to overwrite the file as I don't want the original data preserved.

Comment: What is `csvFile`? Is it a `File`, a `String`? Also, why don't you specify the encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, this:

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(csvFile);
```

truncates the file. Which means you truncate the file at each loop iteration.

Second, `PrintWriter` does not automatically flush its content to the destination and you don't `.flush()` it. Since your file is empty, this also means you probably forget to `.close()` it.

Assuming you use Java 7, use this instead (note: assumes `csvFile` is a `String`; if it is a `File`, use `csvFile.toPath()` in the code extract below instead of `Paths.get(csvFile)`):

```
try (
    final BufferedWriter w = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(csvFile),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(w);
) {
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(A.get(i)+", "+ B.get(i));
        writer.println(A.get(i)+", "+ B.get(i));
    }
    writer.flush();
}
```

Comment: so flush method do 2 thing first will sure that stream is completely cleared and data is written to file  + close the stream ??

Comment: thank you.  this solved my problem.  csvFile is in fact a string.  why do I need to specify encoding? (I am assuming this is what you are doing with the 3rd line)  Sorry.. I am very very new to this.

Comment: Here I use the try-with-resources statement. It will automatically call `.close()` for you. `.flush()` doesn't `.close()`.

Comment: Also, "why do I need to specify encoding?" <-- because by default, the JVM's default encoding will be used when reading/writing text content to file; it differs according to the OS. Specifying the encoding guarantees that the file can be read/written the same way on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Close your PrintWriter  `output.close();`

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(csvFile);
System.out.println(A.get(i)+", "+ B.get(i));
output.println(A.get(i)+", "+ B.get(i));
output.close();
```